# Ionic 2 local storage read issue when build with '--prod'

Tags: android, cordova, angular, ionic-framework, ionic2

I am building an app that does an auto login for the user when app starts if it was closed without logging out the last time. This is done by setting a local storage value at successful login and reading it in the constructor of the landing page, which is the login page.

I used `ionic build android -release` to build and app worked fine. But it takes about 10 sec to load. After some search, I found building the app with `--prod` can reduce the load time and it did reduce my app load time to 4 sec.

But now the app can't read local storage value at the start. No errors., but, it just returns the value as null. In other pages the app can read the local storage though. Looks like some needed components are not fully loaded, when the app reaches the landing page. But, by the time user logins manually those are loaded. How do I implement an auto login while reducing the load time?

```
import { Component } from '@angular/core';
import { NavController, MenuController, NavParams } from 'ionic-angular';
import { AuthService } from '../../providers/auth-service';
import { Global } from '../../providers/global';
import { HomePage } from '../home/home';
import { Storage } from '@ionic/storage';
import { Network } from 'ionic-native';

@Component({
  selector: 'page-login',
  templateUrl: 'login.html'
})
export class LoginPage {

  loginUserID: string = '';
  loginUserPass: string = '';
  showLogin = false;

  constructor(private menu: MenuController, private navCtrl: NavController, private auth: AuthService, private global: Global, private storage: Storage, private navParams: NavParams) {
    this.storage.get('user_id').then((value) => {
      if(this.navParams.get('showLogin')){
        this.showLogin = true;
      }
      else{
        if(value && value != null){
          this.navCtrl.setRoot(HomePage);
        }
        else{
          this.showLogin = true;
        }
      }
    });

    if(this.global.hardwareBackAction != null){
      this.global.hardwareBackAction();
    }
  }

  ionViewDidLoad() {
    this.menu.swipeEnable(false, 'side-menu');
  }

  public login() {
    if (Network.type == 'none') {
      this.global.showAlert('Information', 'No internet access');
    }
    else {
      this.global.showLoading();
      this.auth.login(this.loginUserID, this.loginUserPass).subscribe(allowed => {
            this.global.loading.dismiss();
            if (allowed) {
              setTimeout(() => {
                this.storage.set('user_id', this.loginUserID);
                this.navCtrl.setRoot(HomePage);
              });
            }
          },
          error => {
            this.showError(error);
          });
    }
  }

  showError(text) {
    setTimeout(() => {
      this.global.loading.dismiss();
    });
    this.global.showAlert('Error', text);
  }

}
```

Comment: can you show the landing page code?

Comment: one question, why do you need to have auto logged the user.if a user doesn't log out then app maintains that state no.that mean next time user can use the app without logged in.so why then ?

Comment: but if the user force close the app or close with hardware back button, the app starts fresh and go to login page right ? dont know if im missing something. anyway to login user without typing credentials and without internet while reducing load time is all i want

Comment: hope you can debug no? check whether a `constructor` is being fired on your scenario.it seems not.I think that is the reason which I have mentioned above where app maintains the status even though someone uses the back button of the phone.

Comment: constructor works. storage.get('user_id') also work. its just the value it returns is null. if the app maintains the login status how do i use that? can u pls provide me an example ?

Comment: are you testing on the browser or actual device?

Comment: on a Samsung Galaxy J2

Comment: Can you check if this is correct? `if(value && value != null)`. Won't `if(value !== null)` would be enough. Just asking. I might be wrong as I am not sure what `this.loginUserID` has and from where it is set before passed to LoginPage. Like may be from UI it is set.

Comment: 'loginUserID' is the user id user input when logging in. 'user_id' is set when user successfully log in. 'value && value != null' both used because if the user is using the app for the first time so there is no 'user_id' in local storage and some systems throw an error if only 'value != null' is used